# vim: подсветка синтаксиса, обоснованная первой строкой файла

Tags: linux, vim, nasm, syntax, vimrc

Что необходимо добавить в **~/.vimrc**, чтобы при открытии ***.s** файлов со строкой

```
; vim:ft=nasm
```

в начале файла автоматически включалась подсветка синтаксиса **nasm**? По умолчанию подсвечивается синтаксис **asm**. Каждый раз при открытии ***.s** файла писать **:set ft=nasm** не очень хочется.

Comment: см. https://superuser.com/q/323712/454489 или даже лучше [это](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic#Enabling_modelines)

Comment: а ещё проще в `vimrc` написать `let g:asmsyntax=nasm`... или в начале файла в комментариях прописать `asmsyntax=nasm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set modeline
```

`set modeline` позволяет использовать для текущего файла настройки, указанные в самом начале этого файла (в т.ч. включить в нём подсветку определенного синтаксиса).
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic